# Finder Plugin in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, plugins, osx-snow-leopard, finder

Since the Finder in Snow Leopard has been rewritten to use Cocoa instead of Carbon, I'd like to know if there's a new API to write Finder plugins. The old way involved writing a CFPlugin but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by plug-in you mean contextual menu, you can do this via the services API.

Comment: Is there any way to move my service up (above the Move to Trash)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they prefer that you write Services instead of Finder plugins now.