# Setting the Finder label from Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'd like to programmatically set the Finder label (a.k.a. the color of items in the Finder)  from within Cocoa. I can read the Finder label of a URL `u` without problems using

```
MDItemRef itemRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(NULL, (CFURLRef)u);
CFStringRef s = MDItemCopyAttribute(itemRef, kMDItemFSLabel);
label = [(NSString *)s intValue];
```

This API does not provide any mechanism for writing the metadata, so my guess is that the solution lies elsewhere entirely. Any hints?

Edit: I know this is possible using AppleScript, but this is disallowed under sandboxing. I need a pure in-process solution.

Comment: For 10.6+, try http://stackoverflow.com/a/2785289/483349.

Comment: Thanks, that was fast. If you make your comment in answer form, I'll accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I conditionally color files and folders in the OS X Finder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778855/how-can-i-conditionally-color-files-and-folders-in-the-os-x-finder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Snow Leopard and above, you can utilize the URL Resource API, as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785289/483349).